# $E(|X|^r)<\infty$ if and only if $\sum n^{r-1}P(|X|>n)<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a random variable $X$, how can I show that $\mathbb{E}[|X|^r] < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{r-1} P(|X| > n)<\infty$? I am trying to that trick where I write
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{r-1} P(|X| > n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{r-1} \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{|X| > n \}}] = \mathbf{E}\left [ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{r-1} \mathbf{1}_{\{|X| > n \}} \right ]$$
but it is not really helping.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question and its variations are a Math SE classic. Use [https://approach0.xyz/search/](https://approach0.xyz/search/)

Comment: @Snoop Awesome software!

Answer (score 0):

The usual form of this result involves $P(|X|\ge n)$, but your version is equivalent.

Let $r\ge1$. With $B_k:=\{k\le |X|<k+1\}$, write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{r-1}P(|X|\ge n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{r-1}\sum_{k=n}^\infty P(B_k)=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k n^{r-1}P(B_k);\tag1
$$ the interchange is justified since everything is nonnegative. Recall that $\sum_{n=1}^k n^{r-1}\sim k^r$ as $k\to\infty$ so
$$
\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^k n^{r-1}P(|X|\ge n)<\infty\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^r P(B_k)<\infty.}\tag2$$
But the inequality
$
k^rI(B_k)\le |X|^rI(B_k)\le (k+1)^rI(B_k)
$
implies
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^rP(B_k)\le E|X|^r\le \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^rP(B_k).\tag3$$
Use (3) and the fact that $k^r\sim (k+1)^r$ as $k\to\infty$ to conclude
$$
\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^rP(B_k)<\infty\quad\text{if and only if}\quad E|X|^r<\infty.}\tag4$$